# Reverse page layout in ConTeXt for two-sided RTL document

Tags: context, right-to-left

I'm trying to create a two-sided document in an RTL language. I'd like to reverse the margins, so that the first page has the binding on the right side, rather than on the left.

Obviously I could supply a layout where the inner margin is wider than the outer margin, or insert an empty first page. I'd like to know if there's a right way to do this, however.

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\setupdirections[bidi=global,method=one]
\setupalign[r2l]

\starttext
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you try to achieve isn't possible yet and ConTeXt can only create documents which start with a right side. This means in a single sided document each page is right sided and in a double sided document the first odd page is also a right page.

```
\setuppapersize[A6]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\showframe

\starttext

\dorecurse{3}
  {\doifrightpageelse{Right page}{Left page}\par
   \doifoddpageelse  {Odd page}  {Even page}\page}
\stoptext
```

[image]

A simple hack to to simulate a document which goes from right to left and start with a left page is to increase the `realpage` counter because this skips the first right page and goes to the next left page.

```
\setuppapersize[A6]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\showframe

\setcounter[realpage][2]

\starttext

\dorecurse{3}
  {\doifrightpageelse{Right page}{Left page}\par
   \doifoddpageelse  {Odd page}  {Even page}\page}
\stoptext

\stoptext
```

[image]

While this produces the expected output it can have unwanted side effects because left pages have now even numbers with the internal counter.

The better solution is to ask for a proper implementation of this because it can be done but needs proper testing because many commands have different output for left and right pages.